# why not debug rather why exception handling

Tags: java, exception

we specify the exception in try and catch.If we know what exception is gonna be generated why go for exception handling rather than just debug that part of the code?

Comment: "If we know what exception is gonna be generated "--May not be true always, isn't it?

Comment: Imagine a process that holds a lock on a file. Now you try to do something with that file. You will get an `IOException` and you can decide how your program behaves then. How do you want to debug such a scenario?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Oracle definition of `Exception`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/)

> An **exception is an event** that occurs during the execution of a program **that disrupts the normal flow of instructions**.

**CONCLUSION:**

If you put a `try {} catch` block you know will always trow an Exception, your code is wrong.

For example, this code compiles? YES, but is wrong

```
String s = "throwMe!";
try {
    int number = Integer.parseInt(s);
} catch (NumberFormatException) {
}
```

---

**CORRECT EXCEPTION USE**

```
System.out.println("Enter a number");
String s = Scanner.....     // user enters something
try {
     int number = Integer.parseInt(s);
} catch (NumberFormatException) {
     // TELL USER THERE IS A PROBLEM
}
// TELL USER IS A GENIUS
```

This will have 2 execution flows, the correct one (user is a genius) but in the moment the user enters a value disrupting the flow (`Integer.parseInt(s);`) the Exception is thrown...

Answer (score 0):

No, exceptions refer to run-time conditions that we cannot foresee

For example, the divide-by-zero error happens due to user inputting wrong data.

So you catch with try-catch

```
try {

}
catch(ArithmeticException){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do exception handling or debugging, you can do both and good exception handling helps you debug your code later on.

If nothing else a `catch` block should print the Stack Trace which gives you information regarding where things went wrong with your code and it's much better than failing silently and then manually debug your whole code to search for the problem.

There are [many other advantages](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/advantages.html) to using exceptions for error handling as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try / catch blocks are for errors that you cannot foresee.  Things like null pointers and divide by 0 errors don't need a try catch blocks.  Those things are typically errors on the part of programmers and should be debugged by the programmers.  But things like IOException or SQLException, where you are interfacing with some other system that could fail or give invalid input that the programmer cannot control, those things need a try / catch block.